# Is there a R function for creating an empty edge list (two-mode) with two vectors?

Tags: r

For example, I have two vectors x and y like this.

```
x <-c(1,2,3)
y <-c(4,5,6)
```

I want to create an empty edge list like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pCLQb.png)

Could you please help me?

Comment: What you show looks like the matrix `cbind(x, y)`. How is that an "empty edge list"? Are you using igraph?

Comment: You mean something like `cbind(rep(x, each = 3), rep(y, each = 3))`?

Comment: Oh sorry, a lack of explanation here. I'm actually going to add a third column "weight" once I can create an edge list.

Comment: Thanks, Sotos for the reply. I have two vectors (over 1000 elements each), so I cannot use rep.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you mean with "empty edge list", but is think you could use `tidyr::complete` to find all combinations between x and y.

```
data.frame(x = c(1,2,3), y= c(4,5,6)) %>% 
  tidyr::complete(x,y)
```

`expand.grid` might also do the trick:

```
expand.grid(x = c(1,2,3),y= c(4,5,6))
```